# user input into sed command via variable

Tags: bash, sed, cygwin, mks, ksh

I had this question before and used @HatLess answer when it was going to be static. It needs to be user input and I have tried the script but I am having issues as it tells me file not found and several other messages depending on what I change. I am doing this in a korn shell.

This is an example of my text file

```
126731E             0000000033220422    000003312634460-0003-1
134180D             0000000052220419    000006012622399-0003-1
 134307-004K         0000000016220420    000001612635621-0003-0
 141014-001B         0000000040220419    000004012632585-0003-0
134886C             0000000034220419    000007612620821-0003-1
 123899B             0000000050220412    000005012635007-0003-1
121543C             0000000059220419    000007512621925-0003-1
 118238C             0000000070220419    000007012632584-0003-0
121852A             0000000122220419    000013512622569-0003-1
 123124A             0000000141220419    000014112631954-0003-0
 123157C             0000000344220422    000034412634707-0003-1
```

This is an image of where the date needs to change (highlighted)
[image: highlighted text where date changes]

This is the end result

```
126731E             0000000033220422    000003312634460-0003-1
134180D             0000000052220102    000006012622399-0003-1
 134307-004K         0000000016220420    000001612635621-0003-0
 141014-001B         0000000040220419    000004012632585-0003-0
134886C             0000000034220102    000007612620821-0003-1
 123899B             0000000050220412    000005012635007-0003-1
121543C             0000000059220102    000007512621925-0003-1
 118238C             0000000070220419    000007012632584-0003-0
121852A             0000000122220102    000013512622569-0003-1
 123124A             0000000141220419    000014112631954-0003-0
 123157C             0000000344220422    000034412634707-0003-1
```

220102 would be from a user input and I have that covered but I cannot get it to be used in the sed command. I have tried the sed in the script and calling a separate script. I possibly modified this sed trying to make it work but it still isn't any help.

```
export GLOBAL_UTILS="../../utils"

  broken_date=`$GLOBAL_UTILS/accept_date.ksh "$title" "$message" "$btn_width" "$btn_1_txt" "$btn_2_txt"`
  print $broken_date

    sed -f  [^ ]\+0\+\([1-9]\)\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)\([0-9]\{6\}\)0\+\1\?\2/!{s/[0-9]\{6\}/"$broken_date"/ ../1111003.txt > new.txt
```

accept_date.ksh is just a script that opens a user input box and it works perfect. I get the date entered into the variable I just cannot pass what I entered into the sed command. Thanks in advance

Here is the original sed command

```
/[^ ]* \+0\+\([1-9]\)\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)\([0-9]\{6\}\).* 0\+\1\?\2/!{
    s/[0-9]\{6\} /220102 /
}
```

this is the sed unknown I get which looks like it added the 220909 that I unput but then tells me there is unknown command.

```
+ + echo 220909
RESULT=220909
+ break
+ + echo 220909
+ bc
date_in=220909
+ [ 220909 -lt 200101 ]
+ [ 220909 -gt 501231 ]
+ dlg close
+ break
+ echo 220909
broken_date=220909
  print $broken_date
+ print 220909
220909

    sed -Ee "/[^ ]* +0+([1-9])([0-9]{1,3})([0-9]{6}).* 0+\1?\2/ ! {s/[0-9]{6} /$broken_date /" -e '}' ../1111003.txt > .
./new.txt
+ sed -Ee /[^ ]* +0+([1-9])([0-9]{1,3})([0-9]{6}).* 0+\1?\2/ ! {s/[0-9]{6} /220909 / -e } ../1111003.txt
sed: unknown command
```

Comment: how do u select the lines that should be changed? i can not find any explanation for that.

Comment: The picture has the lines highlighted. They are random but always in column 2 and always before the 22. I hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

You accepted an alternative [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72720442/16372109) to your question but chose to use my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72720489/16372109)? Why not use the accepted solution?

Moving on, your question is a little hard to understand so maybe further clarification may be needed, but, taking your current script, you can try tweaking the `sed` code to work without the command file.

```
export GLOBAL_UTILS="../../utils"

  broken_date=`$GLOBAL_UTILS/accept_date.ksh "$title" "$message" "$btn_width" "$btn_1_txt" "$btn_2_txt"`
  print $broken_date

    sed -Ee "/[^ ]* +0+([1-9])([0-9]{1,3})([0-9]{6}).* 0+\1?\2/ ! {s/[0-9]{6} /$broken_date /" -e '}' ../1111003.txt > new.txt
```

The `-f` flag is for calling a `sed` command file, whereas, in your case, you are using the code directly, so the `-f` flag is not needed.

Comment: I tried the others and they worked but yours seemed easiest to implement since I am still learning. I will give the edits a try and see how it goes. Thanks

Comment: I am using a PC with MKS Toolkit installed and running a korn shell for this. I am getting sed: unknown command and no other description about what is unknown. I will do a little research and see if I can find out why.